# CF two tables have one idea match Name from the other

Tags: coldfusion

I am trying to combine two tables in the first table (dbo.Dealer_Track_Work) I have a dealerID this is ID matches the ID number for the second table (dbo.Dealer_Track_Dealers) and I am trying to have the dealerID match the Name from the second table and display instead of the number. Will someone please tell me where I might be going wrong?

```
<cffunction name="displayTable" access="public" returntype="query">
    <cfset var processTable = ''>
    <cfquery name="processTable">
        SELECT *
        FROM dbo.Dealer_Track_Work, dbo.Dealer_Track_Dealers
        WHERE dbo.Dealer_Track_Work.dealerID = dbo.Dealer_Track_Dealers.Name            
    </cfquery>
    <cfreturn processTable>
</cffunction>

<cfoutput>#Name#</cfoutput>
```

Table 1

[image]

Table2

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't you want to join on id from the dealers table?

Comment: Join on the id from the dealers table and look at your results. Then output #processTable.name#.if that's the only item you need change your select list to reflect that

Comment: Instead of `dbo.Dealer_Track_Dealers.Name` use `dbo.Dealer_Track_Dealers.id` in your where clause

Comment: Glad to help. I've posted as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<cffunction name="displayTable" access="public" returntype="query">
  <cfset var processTable = ''>
  <cfquery name="processTable">
    SELECT name
    FROM dbo.Dealer_Track_Work, dbo.Dealer_Track_Dealers
    WHERE dbo.Dealer_Track_Work.dealerID = dbo.Dealer_Track_Dealers.id          
  </cfquery>
  <cfreturn processTable>
</cffunction>

<cfoutput>#processTable.Name#</cfoutput>
```

Ideally you would use the ANSI join syntax

```
<cffunction name="displayTable" access="public" returntype="query">
  <cfset var processTable = ''>
  <cfquery name="processTable">
    SELECT name
    FROM dbo.Dealer_Track_Work 
      INNER JOIN dbo.Dealer_Track_Dealers ON dbo.Dealer_Track_Work.dealerID = dbo.Dealer_Track_Dealers.id          
  </cfquery>
  <cfreturn processTable>
</cffunction>

<cfoutput>#processTable.Name#</cfoutput>
```